# [obj-c]NSDateで指定曜日の指定時間を取得する

Tags: ios, objective-c

目標としては、取得した日付に対して時間情報を付け加えて、LocalNotificationにセットし
隔週の指定時間に鳴らす。ということを目指しています。

以下のようなコードで指定した曜日を取得しています。

```
- (NSDate *) getDateOfSpecificDay:(NSInteger ) day 
{
    //sunday = 1,monday = 2,...
    NSInteger desiredWeekday = day;
    NSRange weekDateRange = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] maximumRangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday];
    NSInteger daysInWeek = weekDateRange.length - weekDateRange.location + 1;

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger currentWeekday = dateComponents.weekday;
    NSInteger differenceDays = (desiredWeekday - currentWeekday + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek;
    NSDateComponents *daysComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    daysComponents.day = differenceDays;
    NSDate *resultDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:daysComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSLog(@"result:%@",resultDate);
    return resultDate;
}
```

ここに時間情報を加えようと思い、以下のように書き換えてみました。

```
- (NSDate *) getDateOfSpecificDay:(NSInteger ) day hour:(NSInteger)hour minutes:(NSInteger)minutes
{
    //sunday = 1,monday = 2,...
    NSInteger desiredWeekday = day;
    NSRange weekDateRange = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] maximumRangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday];
    NSInteger daysInWeek = weekDateRange.length - weekDateRange.location + 1;

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger currentWeekday = dateComponents.weekday;
    NSInteger differenceDays = (desiredWeekday - currentWeekday + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek;
    NSDateComponents *daysComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    daysComponents.day = differenceDays;
    //add 時
    daysComponents.hour = hour;
    //add 分
    dateComponents.minute = minutes;
    NSDate *resultDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:daysComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSLog(@"result:%@",resultDate);
    return resultDate;
}
```

しかしビルドしても[指定日付,現在時,現在分]でNSDateが帰ってきてしまいます。

原因としては
・dateComponentsやresultDateで[NSDate date]を使ってしまっている
というのではないかと思っているのですが、解決へのアプローチが分かりません。

この改善策を教えて頂けないでしょうか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

時間、分を指定してNSDateを作りたいならばNSCalendarの以下のメソッドで実現できます。

```
- (NSDate *)dateBySettingHour:(NSInteger)h minute:(NSInteger)m second:(NSInteger)s ofDate:(NSDate *)date options:(NSCalendarOptions)opts
```

日付・時間を扱う場合、それがGMTなのかローカル時間なのか意識してください。

日本の場合、GMTと9時間の差があるため、見込んだ結果と9時間ズレたりしがちです。

ざっくりとした実装ですが、以下が参考になれば幸いです。

```
- (NSDate *) getDateOfSpecificDay:(NSInteger ) day hour:(NSInteger)hour minutes:(NSInteger)minutes
{
    //sunday = 1,monday = 2,...
    NSInteger desiredWeekday = day;
    NSRange weekDateRange = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] maximumRangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday];
    NSInteger daysInWeek = weekDateRange.length - weekDateRange.location + 1;

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger currentWeekday = dateComponents.weekday;
    NSInteger differenceDays = (desiredWeekday - currentWeekday + daysInWeek) % daysInWeek;
    NSDateComponents *daysComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    daysComponents.day = differenceDays;
    NSDate *resultDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:daysComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSLog(@"result 1:%@",resultDate);

    // ■ hour, minutesを設定した場合(日本の場合GMTとの時差9時間)
    NSDate *resultDateWithTime = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateBySettingHour:13 minute:minutes second:0 ofDate:resultDate options:NSCalendarMatchStrictly];
    NSLog(@"result 2:%@",resultDateWithTime);

    // ■ TimeZone指定をした場合
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:resultDate];
    NSDateComponents *new_comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [new_comps setYear:comps.year];
    [new_comps setMonth:comps.month];
    [new_comps setDay:comps.day];
    [new_comps setHour:hour];
    [new_comps setMinute:minutes];
    [new_comps setSecond:0];
    NSDate *tmp = [calendar dateFromComponents:new_comps];
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    NSInteger seconds = [tz secondsFromGMTForDate:tmp];
    NSDate *local_date = [tmp dateByAddingTimeInterval:seconds];
    NSLog(@"result 3:%@", local_date);

    return local_date;
}
```